# SELECT NOT IN with multiple columns in subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, inner-join, sql-in

Regarding the statement below, sltrxid can exist as both ardoccrid and ardocdbid. I'm wanting to know how to include both in the NOT IN subquery.

```
SELECT *
FROM glsltransaction A
    INNER JOIN cocustomer B ON A.acctid = B.customerid
WHERE sltrxstate = 4
    AND araccttype = 1
    AND sltrxid NOT IN(
    SELECT ardoccrid,ardocdbid
    FROM arapplyitem)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend `not exists`:

```
SELECT *
FROM glsltransaction t
INNER JOIN cocustomer c ON c.customerid = t.acctid
WHERE 
    ??.sltrxstate = 4
    AND ??.araccttype = 1
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM arapplyitem a
        WHERE ??.sltrxid IN (a.ardoccrid, a.ardocdbid)
    )
```

Note that I changed the table aliases to things that are more meaningful. I would strongly recommend prefixing the column names with the table they belong to, so the query is unambiguous - in absence of any indication, I represented this as `??` in the query.

`IN` sometimes optimize poorly. There are situations where two subqueries are more efficient:

```
SELECT *
FROM glsltransaction t
INNER JOIN cocustomer c ON c.customerid = t.acctid
WHERE 
    ??.sltrxstate = 4
    AND ??.araccttype = 1
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM arapplyitem a
        WHERE ??.sltrxid = a.ardoccrid
    )
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM arapplyitem a
        WHERE ??.sltrxid = a.ardocdbid
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! This did it.